# SUR: Var-Cov matrix becomes singular if maxiter>1

Tags: r, convergence, singular, systemfit

Could you help me with following:
I try to run 5eq simultaneously but I have problems with singularity. My coefficients become very small if  maxiter>1. 
If maxiter>4, R returns the error code

**“Error in .solve.dgC.lu(as(a, "dgCMatrix"), b = b, tol = tol) : 
  LU computationally singular: ratio of extreme entries in |diag(U)| = 3.696e-
  17”**

I am estimating censored LA-AIDS model and the estimation should be possible without dropping any equations. With OLS and WLS everything works fine but the results are biased according to theory..  With SUR convergence is not achieved before the run crashes.
A couple of tables from summary output:

systemfit results when maxiter=1
method: SUR

```
               N    DF   SSR detRCov  OLS-R2   McElroy-R2
      system 16885 16805 595       0  0.042     -0.201

        N   DF   SSR   MSE  RMSE    R2 Adj R2
  eq1 3377 3358  55.4 0.016 0.128 0.034  0.029
  eq2 3377 3358  87.5 0.026 0.161 0.025  0.020
  eq3 3377 3358  87.2 0.026 0.161 0.053  0.048
  eq4 3377 3358 197.8 0.059 0.243 0.053  0.049
  eq5 3377 3358 166.8 0.050 0.223 0.035  0.031
```

The covariance matrix of the residuals used for estimation

```
     eq1      eq2      eq3      eq4      eq5
eq1  0.01594 -0.00227 -0.00165 -0.00662 -0.00516
eq2 -0.00227  0.02558 -0.00333 -0.01114 -0.00848
eq3 -0.00165 -0.00333  0.02579 -0.01248 -0.00796
eq4 -0.00662 -0.01114 -0.01248  0.05758 -0.02703
eq5 -0.00516 -0.00848 -0.00796 -0.02703  0.04922
```

The covariance matrix of the residuals

```
     eq1      eq2      eq3      eq4      eq5
eq1  0.01648 -0.00193 -0.00169 -0.00729 -0.00561
eq2 -0.00193  0.02605 -0.00347 -0.01170 -0.00895
eq3 -0.00169 -0.00347  0.02597 -0.01284 -0.00796
eq4 -0.00729 -0.01170 -0.01284  0.05889 -0.02707
eq5 -0.00561 -0.00895 -0.00796 -0.02707  0.04966
```

The correlations of the residuals

```
       eq1     eq2     eq3    eq4    eq5
eq1  1.0000 -0.0931 -0.0816 -0.234 -0.196
eq2 -0.0931  1.0000 -0.1333 -0.299 -0.249
eq3 -0.0816 -0.1333  1.0000 -0.328 -0.222
eq4 -0.2339 -0.2988 -0.3282  1.000 -0.501
eq5 -0.1962 -0.2488 -0.2217 -0.501  1.000
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance! 
Best Regards Johannes